# Como implementar um código da GameView dentro de uma classe?(em codigo java para android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

sou novo em java e estou desenvolvendo um projeto, tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

paint.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 0, 255));
canvas.drawCircle(xa, ya, 10, paint);

O qual utilizo no método draw da GameView para criar círculos no meu projeto(um game), preciso criar varias classes, uma delas e a classe de nome "jogador", como faço para implementar esse código da GameView na classe jogador por exemplo(se eu não me engano e no construtor da classe)?

O código completo do método draw e esse:

private void draw()  {

```
        if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            paint.setTextSize(30);
            canvas.drawText("PLAY", 250, 250, paint);


            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            paint.setTextSize(30);
            canvas.drawText("SCORE:" + score, 300, 50, paint);


            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 255));
            canvas.drawCircle(xj, yj, 30, paint);

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
```

Quero implementa-lo nessa parte da classe jogador:

```
Jogador(Context context) {


}
```

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Tente postar uma parte do código que você já possuí!

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta